# iOS - should the UIView or the UIViewController handle the state to UI mapping?

Tags: ios, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I've read a few posts but I could not find a clear answer to this question: in the MVC framework, who should be responsible for the UI set up? I'm balancing between two options:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  private var users: [User]
  ...
  override func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = dequeueDataCell(id: "myCell") as? CellView else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.title.text = user?.name
    cell.subtitle.text = user?.nickname
    cell.action.isHidden = isSelected
    // other numerous UI set up on the cell

    return cell
  }
}

class CellView: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel?
  @IBOutlet weak var subtitle: UILabel?
  @IBOutlet weak var action: UIButton!
}
```

and

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  private var users: [User]
  ...
  override func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = dequeueDataCell(id: "myCell") as? CellView else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    cell.isSelected = false
    cell.refresh()

    return cell
  }
}

class CellView: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet private weak var title: UILabel?
  @IBOutlet private weak var subtitle: UILabel?
  @IBOutlet private weak var action: UIButton!

  weak var user: User?
  var isSelected = false

  func refresh() {
    title.text = user?.name
    subtitle.text = user?.nickname
    action.isHidden = isSelected
    // other numerous UI set up on the cell
  }
}
```

I've so far been using the first approach that is found in most iOS tutorials. But I've found that this makes the UIViewController much longer, while they already have a tendency to become long and obscure, and harder to read since it mixes UI and state logic.